# Two different html templates

Tags: html, templates

I am trying to add two html templates in one site one is normal and other for mobile devices.

I want that when someone see my site with mobile it show mobile template instead of normal.

Is it possible?

I discuss this other people they says install parallel site eg: m.atecharea.com and use config file for regular site and name the template file as in regular site . With this method everything goes correct except one thing data folder not loaded which is in root/ directory. They also suggest to change data path manually from this:

```
// Data paths
define('MEDIA_DIR', 'data/media');
```

to this

```
// Data paths
define('MEDIA_DIR', 'http://m.atecharea.com/data/media');
```

its not work, it shows data folder link like this

http://atecharea.com/http://m.site.com/data/media

**its not work**

Other person suggest to load wap template instead of default when view through mobile url.
Code is this:

```
if ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'] == 'm.atecharea.com') {
    $config['template_dir'] = $config['template_dir'] . 'default_wap';
}
```

it didn't work either.

Please if some one guide to get data folder **or** second template folder anyone solution from these two will solve my problem

Comment: That would very much depend on how you're serving the pages.

Comment: Yes. And that's the most informative answer you can get with the level of detail in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not very specific so a suitable answer would be "Yes". You can try to detect the browser using the user-agent and then send the desired HTML back to the client based on that.

Also there are two widely used alternatives to that:

1. use an adaptive/responsive layout, meaning one layout that is built in such
   a way that it adapts itself any screen
2. use a standalone domain for the mobile pages